# Can't access a variable defined in another template despite using GLOBAL

Tags: variables

I created, populated and successfully echoed a variable `x` in `header.php`. Then in my front page template I did `global $x` then `echo $x`. This displays nothing. Why?

Comment: Did you declare `global $x;` in `header.php` ?

Comment: Just don't use globals. If you are trying to do some kind of optimization, then you are most likely trying to do something that is totally not needed